# jQuery UI : How can I convert an element into a circle while sorting or dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui

I want to know that I can I convert an element into a circle while sorting or dragging it (the element) including its child elements. I have tried but its incomplete.

```
$('#editorDesignView').sortable({
       cursor: 'move',
     start: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.item).addClass("sortable-change");
     },
     stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.item).removeClass("sortable-change");
     }
});
```

Updated:

```
$('#editorDesignView').sortable({
        // opacity: 0.6,
        handle: ".draggable-area",
        cursor: 'move',
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            $(ui.item).addClass("on-sortable-change");
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(ui.item).removeClass("on-sortable-change");
        }
    });
```

[My jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/pL4Lv6r9/72/)

Comment: could you please let me know what is incomplete here?

Comment: @vijayP Please check the codepen link try to drag n drop the element and  sort it the element radius will change but as I want to do it is not happening

Comment: sorry but still not not clear about the exact output. Are you facing issue with circle radius. If so then you may check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvVRgz

Comment: @vijayP Yes this is it. But one thing is left and that is the title and para should also disapperar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of converting an element by applying CSS there is standard way to achieve your goal. Its as follows:

```
$('#editorDesignView').sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: function(){
       return $("<div class='sortable-change'></div>");
    },
    cursorAt: { left: -60, top: 20 }
});
```

We can use [helper](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper) option and [cursorAt](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cursorAt) option while initializing `sortable`

Updated codepen can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvVRgz

Comment: I want to ask one thing how can I set the position ( means if I drag the element from its end the problem is the circle is very far away form the cursor )

Comment: I am have one problem I have already made a handler for sorting the element because it is overtaking the contenteditable elements so can I  declare more than one handlers here is the link for that https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/pL4Lv6r9/72/

Comment: could you please post your code. I am not able to visualize your code so can't comment anything as of now.